# Intuitiveness for Condition Distribution of a Multivariate Normal (MVN) Random Variable?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, intuition, multivariate-normal-distribution

One of the results of multivariate normal distributions is that if $X\sim MVN_{k}(\mu, \Sigma)$ and the following are partitioned vectors (and matrix):

$\mathbf{X}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{\mathbf{X_{(1)}}}\\
\mathbf{X_{(2)}}
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\mu}}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{\mathbf{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\mu}}_{(1)}}}\\
\mathbf{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\mu}}_{(2)}}
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{11}}} & \mathbf{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12}}}\\
\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{21}} & \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{22}}
\end{bmatrix}$

where $\mathbf{\mathbf{X_{(1)}}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ are $p\times1$, then:

$X_{(1)}|X_{(2)}=x_{(2)}\sim MVN_{p}(\mathbf{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\mu}}_{(1)}+\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12}}\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22}^{-1}}(\mathbf{x_{(2)}}-\mathbf{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\mu}}_{(2)}}),\,\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{11}-\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22}^{-1}}\mathbf{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{21}})$

Can someone provide and intuitive explanation of why this is the case?  How might one quickly go about recalling this formula?  I have a terrible memory and usually have to derive many of the formulas I need (since I can rarely remember them on the fly), so I was wondering if there was an intuitive way to recall this.  Why is this the form of the conditional MVN formula, intuitively?

Comment: Hi: I don't know one for the variance but, for the new mean of $x_1$, you can think of it this way. You observe the value of $x_2$ so have a measure for the distance between $x_2$ and what you expected to see ( the mean, $\mu_2$ ). So, to get an estimate of the new mean of $x_1$, $\mu_1$,  you take some fraction of that observed distance. This fraction  is the ratio of covariance of the two rv's to the variance of $x_2$. So, you're standardizing the covariance in order to obtain the factor to muitiply by. It's related to what's done in exponential smoothing and adaptive expectations.

Comment: Note that your variable before the $\sim MVN$, should probably be $x_{1|2}$ rather than $x_{2}$.